# Initiate jagged list

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to make a jagged list. It gets filled with values depending on two variable int's: rows, and cols.

The pattern is to have the list filled like this when rows = 4 and cols = 3:

```
00,
10,
20,
01,
11,
21,
02,
12,
22,
03,
13,
23
```

Each double digit is a sub-list containing column, and then row.
This is what i have:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            defineCellPositionsList();
            displayCellPositionsList();
        }

        int rows = 4;
        int cols = 3;

        private List<List<int>> CellPositionsList = new List<List<int>>();

        private void defineCellPositionsList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++)
            {
                List<int> sublist = new List<int>();
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                    {
                        sublist.Add(col);
                        sublist.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                CellPositionsList.Add(sublist);
            }
        }

        private void displayCellPositionsList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CellPositionsList.Count; i++)
            {
                label1.Text += CellPositionsList[i][0];
                label1.Text += CellPositionsList[i][1] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The jagged list should have 12 sub-lists. The sub-lists should have 2 values. This is working. However each value is 0. Clearly i am slightly off with my logic. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your example seems to describe an one-dimensional list, yet the code creates a list of lists. Which is it?

Comment: It describes a jagged list. It states that each double digit is a sublist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that each of your sublists is `{ 0, 0 }`, but rather that *each one is a sublist of the full 24 items*, which happens to begin with the numbers `0, 0`. You can verify this by checking `CellPositionsList[i].Count`.

The bug is due to too much looping when the lists are created. You don't need three loops, two are correct:

```
private void defineCellPositionsList()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            CellPositionsList.Add(new List<int> { col, row });
        }
    }
}
```

And there is also no need to write all of this longhand, as LINQ provides an IMHO better alternative:

```
CellPositionsList = Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
    .SelectMany(r => Enumerable.Range(0, cols).Select(c => new List<int> {c,r}))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. The output in the form label needs to be exactly the same as my example output (without commas as i didn't add them into the label). Assuming i did displayCellPositionsList() correctly, this doesn't seem to create the jagged list i want.

Comment: @user2602079: Assuming "this" is the LINQ version, I just realized I had incorrectly swapped `c` and `r`. Fixed (they are now in line with the loop version). Was that it?

Comment: I originally tested your top version which doesn't work, but now i have tested your LINQ version and it works thank you. I find it hard to understand though as i am not familiar with LINQ.

Comment: @user2602079: Turns out it didn't work because I 'm dumb, or because it's late, or both. Edited to fix, thanks for the feedback. <embarrassed>

Comment: Haha, no, you've been a big help. Both solutions work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`defineCellPositionsList()` seems to be using the same `sublist` for every iteration.  The first two elements in `sublist` are `0, 0`, but there are a total of 24 eventually added.</strike>

To fix this, move the declaration of `sublist` inside the first loop.

I do see plenty of non-zero values in the sublists.  It may be worth noting that you appear to be putting all the values into a single label in `displayCellPositionsList`.

**I was totally wrong about that stuff.**

But this stuff is right.  I've executed and it works.  (assuming I understand what you're trying to do, it's still a little vague)

If you have a list of rows, and a list of columns, and then finally a 2-list of coordinates, then you really have 3 sets of nested lists.  I'm not sure exactly what you're doing or why you want it that way, but if that's what you really want, then your `CellPositionsList` really needs to be `List<List<List<int>>>`.  If you do that, you can use this code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    CellPositionsList.Add(new List<List<int>>());
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        CellPositionsList[row].Add(new List<int> {row, col});
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post a code example of the change? I have tried a couple of things i think you meant, each with promising results (the numbers were not all 0) but it didn't quite work. I want to display the whole jagged list in one label, just to check each value in the list. Before i made your changes, it was all 0's in the label.

Comment: It has a few errors. You may want to copy paste my original code and then make your changes if you have the time. No worries if not though, thanks for your help.